# Why is this SQL statement not executing?

Tags: sql

I have an SQL statement without a where clause because I want it to affect all rows. I have a column with the name url. Now I want to change the current column url to something else. I want to concatenate something to the current url.

My statement is:

```
 UPDATE tablename SET url = 'http' || url;
```

This is in a sql file, which executes and throws no errors but the database is not changing.

Can anyone help?

RDBMS is MySQL

Comment: What RDBMS to be sure?

Comment: tsql uses ( + ) for concat... are you using oracle... or some other sql language?  in tsql the || is a bitwise operator

Comment: Also, how are you running the file?

Comment: Certainly that code will not work with all SQL databases. It would fail in SQL Server for instance that uses a + for concatentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your engine (in case it isn't Oracle and you have some bizarre MySQL bitwise operator)

```
UPDATE tablename SET url = CONCAT('http', url);
```

or

```
UPDATE tablename SET url = 'http' + url;
```

Comment: @user953278: Thanks What RDBMS though please?

Answer (score 3):

(Assuming its an Oracle DB)
I guess you are not commiting the changes and checking for the changes in other session.

Change your script file to:

```
UPDATE tablename SET url = 'http' || url; 
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 2):

You may need to commit the transaction if commit is not implicit.
Try

```
COMMIT;
```